# Excel cell's ShrinkToFit property: detect when font size is shrunk?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

If the ShrinkToFit property for an Excel worksheet cell is set to True, Excel shrinks the font size to fit all the text if necessary.

Is it possible in VBA to detect if the font size for such a cell has been shrunk? Easy to see it happen with my eyes, but I need to detect it with VBA.

Please note I am NOT asking how to check whether the ShrinkToFit property has been set to True. Nothing could be easier than that. I'm asking how to check whether the font size for the cell has actually been shrunk, which only happens if necessary to fit all the text.

Comment: Greg, I'm looking for the same thing, have you come across an answer to this?

Comment: Hi @DaveU, I didn't find a solution but I do have an idea; please see the answer I just posted below.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, I'll play around with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a solution and decided to go a different direction. However, since then I've had this idea, which I've not tested:

Make a hidden sheet or workbook, and copy the cell to a cell there. Copy the column width too. Turn Shrink to fit OFF on that worksheet. Check the column width. Now do an autofit on that column. Now check the column width again. Did autofit widen the column (again, with ShrinkToFit turned off)? If so, then I think it's a safe bet that it's shrunk in the original.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to check ShrinkToFit, considering Cell A1 in Sheet1 in this example:

```
Sub test()

    Dim rngRange As Range

    'Assign Range
    Set rngRange = Sheet1.Range("A1")
    'Set shrinkto fit as true
    rngRange.ShrinkToFit = True
    'Check whether cell is Shrink to fit or not
    If rngRange.ShrinkToFit Then
        'Set Shrinktofit as false or do something
        rngRange.ShrinkToFit = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Jur Pertin, that is NOT what I mean. Anyone who knows how to set the property knows how to check it too. I'm not asking about checking whether the ShrinkToFit property is set to True or False. I'm talking about checking whether the font size for the cell has actually been shrunk. Just because the ShrinkToFit property has been set to True does not mean that the font size is actually shrunk; that only happens if the the font size needs to be shrunk to fit it all.